# Is it illegal to take a piece of the Berlin Wall?

Tags: legal, germany, berlin, landmarks, souvenirs

As a keepsake for my traveling in Germany,  I would like to take a pebble from the Berlin Wall-is it illegal (or perhaps frowned upon) to do so? I'm aware that they sell (presumably fake) pieces in gift shops,  however to me that would defeat the purpose. 
Moreover,  I'm not entirely sure where to go to actually get a piece (I assume museums are protective of their assets).

EDIT: Thanks @Fiksdal for the answer - while the answer for this question may be fairly obvious, it seems like the legality has flexed over time (as @Jan pointed out, now people are too late to partake in it).

Perhaps even more importantly, when you Google 'Is it illegal to take a piece of the Berlin Wall', nothing useful shows up (save now for this question)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44979/discussion-on-question-by-schil227-is-it-illegal-to-take-a-piece-of-the-berlin-w).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Edit:** The new [answer by Jack](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77923/41775) is quite excellent! However, *unless doing something like that*, then:

There was a lot of leftover debris while the Berlin Wall was being demolished. That, however, was a long time ago and parts of the Berlin Wall are now being intentionally maintained<sup>*</sup> as a historical monument. Therefore, removing pieces of it without permission can now only be described as *vandalism*.

*Vandalism* is a crime in Germany and punishable by fines, and/or anything from a few weeks to two years of imprisonment (depending on seriousness and history) according to German Penal Code [(§ 303 StGB)](http://www.express.de/geldstrafen-oder-haft-diese-strafen-drohen-vandalen-22071224).

Also, as @PeterM says in a comment, you may consider it just a "pebble", but this is an important historical monument, and it could easily be partly ruined if (hundreds of) thousands of tourists took a small piece each over the decades. Also, different people may have different opinions on what constitutes a "small piece".

---

<sup>I've been asked in several comments to explain why I consider removing pieces from the Berlin Wall to be vandalism.
The [definition of *vandalism*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vandalism) is:</sup>

> The act of deliberately destroying or damaging property.

Looking at this definition, I think it's self-explanatory that whenever you remove a part of any structure without permission, then that's vandalism. In the case of the Berlin Wall, it's also probably serious, because there's a risk that a large number of people will do it. That is, of course, not to mention the fact that the Berlin Wall is one of Europe's most important historical monuments, and carefully maintained as such. (At least parts of it.)
* = If you seek out one of the [obscure parts of the wall](http://www.seetheworldinmyeyes.com/historical-architecture/what-is-left-of-the-berlin-wall-after-25-years/) (these may not be considered monuments, I'm not sure) you **may** find a piece of it that's already broken off and lying on the ground next to it. *Maybe* you could somehow manage to confirm that this was indeed once a part of the wall. Given such a lucky find, picking it up and taking it might not be illegal. Anyway, instead of going through all that trouble (confirmation, etc.), Jack's answer is probably a safer bet.

Related: [How can I determine if there's a way I can legally take home a piece of a particular landmark?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/77982/41775)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47261/discussion-on-answer-by-fiksdal-is-it-illegal-to-take-a-piece-of-the-berlin-wall).

Answer (score 65):

There is a hotel in Berlin that lets you chip away your own pieces of the wall and take them with you as part of [a package deal](http://www.westingrandberlin.com/en/berlin-wall-package). So there do still exist legal options for you to take your own piece home.

Comment: But do they provide a David Hasselhoff soundtrack to properly get you into that late-80s/early-90s Germany vibe?

Comment: @Graham Unless this is the case, then this answer should be deleted as "very low quality" or "not an answer", IMO.

Comment: @Fiksdal who would travel to Berlin without bringing their own David Hasselhoff soundtrack? Some essential travel equipment just goes without saying: if hiking, bring appropriate shoes; if going to Berlin, bring the Hoff.

Comment: @user568458 Touché.

Comment: More generally, considering the size of the wall before its deconstruction, I am sure many of the souvenir pieces sold in tourist shops are genuine.

Comment: I was in Berlin in summer 1991.  During the day, I saw people with tables selling pieces of the wall right in front of it.  That evening, the sellers were replaced with homemade signs saying not to take pieces of the wall.  Hmmm...

Comment: Plus, the package comes with "Berlin-style curried sausage and a glass of Champagne", which is the most un-currywurst-ish way I've ever seen to describe currywurst.

Comment: @Graham Why bring the soundtrack? For the full experience, just bring the man himself. I'm sure he won't mind humming a tune while you whittle away remnants of world war ii era imperialism.

Comment: @E.P. Currywurst and champagne is just ***wrong***.

Answer (score 55):

This contradicts travel etiquette more generally. (Barring some more specific local ethic saying it's okay, but that doesn't seem to exist here). The ethic is known as [Leave No Trace](https://lnt.org/) ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_No_Trace)) and is developed for respecting the outdoors, but in my opinion, perfectly well applies here.

Taking a pebble or stick or leaf when on "sacred" grounds, whether it be a historical monument or a U.S. national park, is in violation of this ethic. Historical monuments should be preserved for hundreds or thousands of years and enjoyed by thousands or millions of people. "Taking a pebble" is simply unsustainable at that scale.

The issue is not whether there are enough pebbles to cover all the ravenous tourists. The issue is that tourists are engaging in the "take" ethic in the first place, and in seeking something for yourself special that you alone can enjoy, you are, naturally, seeking something that others cannot take. The pebble is an interesting example because it apparently is unique and hard to obtain, but subtle enough that maybe a tourist can get away with taking one. If pebbles were okay to take, you would *know* that already. It would be in the tour books or notated at the exhibit, and, possibly, be no more special to you than a photograph.

So, kudos to you for researching this cautiously. I just want to emphasize that the most general answer is *don't do it*, barring *specific* permissions from the local authority responsible for preserving the site.

Comment: Very good answer - while it doesn't speak to the legality of this specific question, I'll be more mindful when traveling of the greater consequences.

Comment: I have a question regarding taking a leaf from US National parks, not sure if it's worth it's own question. Are you saying I can not take a fallen leaf of the ground at a US National Park?

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 I really, really, really doubt anyone will care if you take a leaf from a U.S. national park. However, [you should avoid taking bison](http://www.cnn.com/2016/05/16/health/yellowstone-bison-calf-euthanasia-good-intention-trnd/).

Comment: @reirab Darn, that was just what I was after. ;)

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 no, you definitely shouldn't. You shouldn't be trying to find sufficiently minute things to take from parks in the first place.

Comment: @Jane: You should also take care to sluice yourself down properly before leaving, in case any pollen or anything has settled on you ;-) But actually that's OK because as djechlin says, the issue isn't the significance of what you take, it's the intention to take anything. I don't know what specific statutes cover US National Parks but there is a general concept of "de minimis" by which even if illegal, an act can be so insignificant the court won't consider it. But don't go around expecting de minimis exceptions from theft or similar laws, unless you've had solid legal advice to that effect...

Comment: @djechlin well to each their hobby right? I make travel journals in which I like to collect things like receipts, tickets and dried leaves.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 You should not take leaves from parks. http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/3856/4038

Comment: One should, however, be aware of the possibly high amount *asbestos concentration* that the last generation of the wall segments contained. This is just another reason why such things should not be done.

Answer (score 10):

The [gift shop at the Checkpoint Charlie / Berlin Wall museum](http://www.mauermuseum.de/index.php/en/shop-and-cafe) sells small chunks of the wall in various forms (e.g. encased in plastic at the end of a bookmark) for reasonable prices, like a couple Euros (at least in 2005 when I was there).  I'm possibly mis-remembering which gift-shop I got the bookmark from; I gave it as a gift so I don't still have it.

[The museum](http://www.mauermuseum.de/) is worth a visit; there's some neat stuff ranging from homebrew radios to Stalin propaganda.  Also stuff about the various iterations of the wall, and news reports of the first person to attempt to escape, and other notable things.

Also very cool was a tour of a sentry tower, but this was a private individual who (IIRC) was the brother of the first person to be killed trying to escape East Berlin after the wall went up.  He didn't speak much English, but apparently spends some of his time passing on the history of the place to tourists.  I got the impression that this was just something he does personally, not getting paid for it by a museum or anything.  This was 10 years ago, and he wasn't a young guy then.

---

Back to the souvenirs:  At the higher end of the price range, there were paper weights (again clear plastic) with bigger chunks (larger than pebble size).  The chunks all had a piece of the surface visible, usually with some graffiti, so you could tell it wasn't just any random pebble.

If you really wanted the bare chunk, you could just buy a bookmark and crack the plastic.  Or maybe find a different tourist shop than the one I visited, if this isn't unique to that museum.