# How can I determine if there's a way I can legally take home a piece of a particular landmark?

Tags: legal, souvenirs

Considering to the question of [Is it illegal to take a piece of the Berlin Wall](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77893/is-it-illegal-to-take-a-piece-of-the-berlin-wall), I am interested in knowing what other historical landmarks or sites one can legally and safely take home a piece.

Specifically, **how would one determine** if an arbitrary landmark has a legal route for acquiring a piece? In the case of the linked question, it was sheer luck that someone who knew a workaround frequents Travel.SE and saw the question.

Consider the avid traveler who might start a personal pebble-sized museum of historical places he had visited. The linked question suggests that he could add the Berlin Wall to his museum. What else could he legally add? The Great Wall of China? The Great Sphinx of Giza?

Comment: Legally is clear enough, but what do you consider as "safely"?

Comment: I would dare say that most landmarks would not allow removal of items, as that would diminish that landmark.  The Berlin Wall on the other hand IS something they wanted destroyed.

Comment: @mts: By "safely" I mean without causing or increasing the chances of causing harm to one's self or to others.

Comment: Isn't this the bad kind of list question?

Comment: @hippietrail: Note that I'm asking **how would one determine if an arbitrary landmark has a legal route for acquiring a piece**. Though I would absolutely _love_ a list of such places, א) I'm not asking that, and ב) That might actually be a great list question!

Comment: Your `surprising` answer is predicated on the site in question being declared as scrap.  The two possibilities you name have not been designated as such, and removing things from them should be considered vandalism (and already have problems with people taking things from them).  So if you really are serious, then you should make up a list of piles of rubbish with a verifiable provenance.  Which I guess will be a very small list.

Comment: @dotancohen: Rule of thumb: If it's recognized as a historical site or a landmark then leave it the * alone. You're twenty something years too late for the Berlin wall. The free for all is over and the last bits are protected because they're the last bits. Anything condemned, under demolition, or forsaken is fair game. I suggest taking your chisel and baggies around some of Saddam's former palaces in Iraq.

Comment: The Grand Canyon is a UNESCO world heritage landmark. Don't think anyone would mind if you took a rock home...

Comment: @Berwyn check out #11 https://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/backcountry-regs.htm

Comment: @Kent Good to know!

Comment: If the site is important enough to have a website you may find a line on its website, mostly that reads that you are not allowed to take anything but pictures and often not anything but good memories. I do remember big national parks which had a line on the entry signs stating that taking even one pebble is not allowed.

Comment: @PeterM: You are right, and that is a good answer. Please post your comment as an answer. If other historical landmarks are declared as scrap, for instance perhaps the Saturn V first and second stages on the bottom of the ocean, then perhaps an enterprising souvenir hunter might go after them if it is legal.

Comment: @dotancohen: Treasure hunting apparently has tons of complex rules that vary by where in the world, chain of ownership, and god knows what else. No references but I've watched a few documentaries on professional treasure hunting operations.

Comment: If you have a time machine, you could visit Stonehenge before 1900. But I assume you don't have one, which is why I'm only posting this as a comment.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Actually the time machine won't go above about 30 degrees north or south of the equator as the calculations for determining where the surface of the geoid of the Earth will be become exponentially more difficult at higher latitudes and I run the risk of stack overflowing out in the ether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to determine this, one could ask:

1. People with the appropriate authority in local law enforcement (police, etc.) in the jurisdiction in which the monument is located.
2. If it exists, the management of any museum, memorial center or other such organization related to the site.
3. Possibly a local lawyer.

Hopefully, they will tell one to go to a giftshop or something like that. Or they may inform one of something like the [special hotel in Berlin.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77923/41775)

If one got a yes from all these, then I suppose one could go ahead, but only in the exact manner advised.

If one  got a "no" from any one of these, I would advise against doing it.

I want to say that I believe it's extremely unlikely that one is going to find a historic landmark where such people will tell one to go ahead and chip off a piece for oneself. If one is looking for that, one will be wasting one's time the vast majority of the time. It's better to go and enjoy one's holiday than to waste one's time in such pursuits.

Moreover, while I understand that some people might be, I would not personally be interested in chipping off a piece of a monument, even with explicit permission. I believe that the beauty of a monument is in the very location, not in taking pieces away for oneself. However, that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I agree with you on everything but the last; were everyone to take a tiny piece, eventually a very visible dent would appear. Perhaps it would be best to visit the souvenir/gift shop and, if there's a pebble encased in a hunk of plastic, buy it.

Comment: @Dorothy You're right. Updated.